# How to fix this error in the frontend after upgrading Typo3?

Tags: debian-wheezy, typo3

I am in the process of upgrading a site in Typo3 from the version included in Debian Wheezy, that is version 4.5.19, to the LTS-version 6.2.12. I have gone through most of the process and backend already works, but in the frontend I have only an error-message and don't know how to fix this currently. The message is:

```
PHP Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository::__construct() must implement interface TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface, none given, called in /usr/share/typo3/typo3-6.2/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 4432 and defined in /usr/share/typo3/typo3-6.2/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Repository.php line 75

More information regarding this error might be available online.
```

The link leads me [here](http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1), but that isn't really of help. Can anyone provide an idea what to check/change?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some tries I found the reason. I was going through the extension-manager and deactivating extensions and it turned out a self-programmed extension was producing this error. We still look into this, but the general recommendation ist to deactivate extensions and try again until you found the troublemaker.